# Enviar variable header error con carácter #

Tags: php

estoy enviando variables por medio url

```
 header("Location:/home-2/?$url");
```

Cuando paso variables sencillas con numero o textos comunes pasan normal cuando es una dirección que tiene el carácter #, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
PHP Warning:  Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in
```

Alguien podría echarme una mano. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error: *`... new line detected in ...`*, parece indicar que hay saltos de línea en los datos.

Prueba a limpiar el dato antes de pasarlo al location.

Imaginemos que aquí `$str` es el dato, puedes hacer algo así:

```
$url = trim( str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\n\r", "<br>","<br />"), '', $str) );
header("Location:/home-2/?$url");
```

No obstante, deberías también revisar los datos guardados en la base de datos, eliminando allí los posibles saltos de línea que haya.